# Changing the timezone using php

Tags: php, datetime

i'm using a shared server with default timezone -06:00 (US) but all the users in the website are in +03:00 timezone.
can i change the time displayed to the user by only using php because there is no way to modify the server settings.
i searched a lot and tried to set the timezone using .htaccess using this code

```
SetEnv TZ America/Indianapolis
```

and also i added this code at the beginning of the php code

```
putenv("TZ=Asia/Baghdad");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Baghdad");
```

but still no change

this is how i display the date and time:

```
echo date('Y-m-d / h:i a', strtotime($articles_info['date']));
```

It maybe an easy solution but i still in the process of learning.
thanks alot..

Comment: Why not pass the timezone when you `strtotime()` the date?

Comment: i didn't find a way like this in php manual, can you help with syntax @Darren

Comment: Sure thing mate, what does `$articles_info['date']` look like? You could try something like: `strtotime($articles_info['date'] . ' +0300');`

Comment: 2016-11-22 05:31:44 (this is a sample of $articles_info['date']) ok i will try this right away

Comment: Try what I posted just before your comment :-)

Comment: You show `$articles_info['date']` in comment, but what does the `date()` call output?

Comment: the input is  2016-11-22 / 05:31:44 am @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no timezone as part of the date/time `$articles_info['date']`, how does PHP know to change the date/time to the default?  As far as PHP knows, the date/time is already in the default timezone.  Tell it the timezone of the provided date/time:

```
echo date('Y-m-d / h:i a', strtotime($articles_info['date'] . ' America/Chicago'));
```

-6:00 should be Central Time, but since we don't know if it's standard (CST) or Daylight (CDT), try `America/Chicago`.

Comment: Hrm, that's a different way of doing it, got my vote! Nice.